# How to include twig templates using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig

I have a web form page with the possibility to add dynamically other fields by clicking onto a link. This page it's been splitted into various templates, in particular every field of the form has it's own template. Now to make this work I have to copy and paste the final generated html code and assign it manipulating the DOM, is there a way to let Jquery reuse my already written TWIG templates?

For an example of my situation take a look at: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype

Comment: Actually I took the road of using the TWIG macros, it's more customizable, anyway the rendered html is the default one that you can see by calling the form_row() function. Can anyone help me to find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know whether I understand you well. I 'n my project I have `Profile` entity with collection of `Study` entity. `ProfileType` has

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
            ->add('studies', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new StudyType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                    )
            )
...
```

And in template after list of studies I have `Add new` button with JS code

```
    var children, classParts, nr, proto;
    children = $('#profile_' + name).children();
    if (children.size()) {
        classParts = children.last().attr('class').split('_');
        nr = classParts.pop()*1 + 1;
    } else {
        nr = 0;
    }
    proto = $('#profile_' + name + '').data('prototype');
    proto = proto.replace(/\$\$name\$\$/g, nr);
    $('#profile_' + name + '').append(proto)
```

This is working because in rendered form I have prototype for new `Study` form.